# Connect to a shared location username and password from bash file

Tags: bash, scripting, terminal

I have a shared location which requires username and password. On my linux machine I can access it from nautlis by entering the username and password, but when I try to access it from a .sh file as shown below it says `permission denied error 13`.

```
#!/bin/bash -i
min_age=5
mydir="smb://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/my-shared-loc/"
rsync_extra_opts='-ptOW --info=progress2 --no-super --remove-source-files'
find . -type f -mmin +$min_age -print0 | rsync -0 --files-from=- $rsync_extra_opts ./ "$mydir/"
```

Comment: @Kusalananda I've updated the question

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry, updated it.

Answer (score 0):

`rsync` does not recognise Samba shares (locations with a `smb://` prefix), only local pathnames and `user@host:/some/path`-type names (with which it will use SSH by default).

If your Samba share is mounted as a local directory, then try using `rsync` against that instead.